# Macro to print to the visual studio debugger

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple macro to append a break line to it. Is it the right do this?:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(message, ...)   \
                message += "\n"; \
                _RPTN(0, message, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And to use:

```
DEBUG_PRINT("my messages %s %d", anotherString, someNumber)
```

Also for some reason the compiler doesn't accepts it with a message: 
`Cannot assign to an array type 'char const[theSizeOfTheString]'`

Thanks for the answers in advance! :)

Comment: That's not how you concatenate constant string literals in C++. Try doing e.g. `std::cout << "foo" "bar" "\n":` and see what you get.

Comment: Hmm...That's interesting. That's the moment where C#/Java developers looking at this like so: 0.o. So you're saying I should do it like this if I understand you correctly: _RPTN(0, message "\n", __VA_ARGS__);

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just use `OutputDebugString` instead of macros?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks Richard, but I'm already aware of this one and I didn't like the fact that you need to create for it a buffer and do some sprintf to format your string before passing it to the OutputDebugString.

Comment: @GiladReich Guess what - all that has to happen anyway (behind the scenes). Using `OutputDebugString`  you remain in control.

Comment: @RichardCritten To be completely honest, I don't consider my self as advance C++ programmer, but always interested to learn. So do you mind please sharing the benefits of it in comparison to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `message` is going to be a constant string, you could do it like this:

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(message, ...) _RPTN(0, message "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

For more details, see string literals at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> String literals placed side-by-side are concatenated at translation
>   phase 6 (after the preprocessor). That is, `"Hello,"  " world!"` yields
>   the (single) string `"Hello, world!"`. If the two strings have the same
>   encoding prefix (or neither has one), the resulting string will have
>   the same encoding prefix (or no prefix).